# Location: $GLOBALS

Tags: php, location

Hey im doing a logincheck, and i want to set the location to the previous page.

On my site with the form, where i set username and password:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['returnsite'] = 'login.php';
?>
```

And on the checker site, which checks if the name and pass match:

```
<?php
header('Location: '.$GLOBALS['returnsite']);
?>
```

It doesnt return, and i get this error "Notice: Undefined index: returnsite"

How can i make a "global variable" which can be set in the header('Location: '.$myvar);
??

Comment: Why do you expect globals to work? Does that mean you expect *every* visitor to share the same globals array? Wouldn't that be bad?

Comment: Im not 100% sure about how $GLOBALS work, but i only need it in use to save a link adress, which is for every visitor

Comment: Globals are just a super global *variable scope* inside a PHP script. Separate PHP script instances still do not share data with them. What you want are cookies and/or sessions. You'll need to learn about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark says in his comment `$GLOBALS` is not persistent.

I would suggest you use sessions instead:

Page with the form: (on line 1!)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['returnsite'] = 'login.php';
?>
```

On the "checker" page: (line 1!)

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

Then after you have processed the login:

```
header("Location: {$_SESSION['returnsite']}\r\n");
exit;
```

Comment: first thank you for the quick answer.

But i've used $_SESSION before, and i have trouble with it, when putting it online, because the SESSIONID changing all the time.

So i would prefer using something else?

Comment: It sounds to me like your browsers cookie settings are not allowing session cookies, I can't think why the session would regenerate it's id all the time

Comment: It's been the same problem at 8 different computers (diff. OS). So i hope there could be an other solution?

Comment: php sessions are a well-established feature and used by a large number of sites to provide persistent data between page loads. They are the correct answer to your question. If they're not working for you, then you're doing something wrong. Possibly you're not starting the session correctly, or you've got something broken in your php.ini config. Either way if $_SESSION isn't working, how do you expect to have a working and secure login system? Sessions is what you need. There aren't any better solutions to this, and $GLOBALS certainly ain't it.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, i'll search for more knowledge about the $_SESSION then :). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is just pass the redirect URL through as a GET variable.

Example:

```
checker.php?returnsite=login.php
```

and then you would use:

```
header('Location: ' . $_GET["returnsite"]);
```

Comment: This is just as useful as my suggestion and avoids the OP's fear of sessions :)